# Concatenation of Pandas Dataframes takes extremely long

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Im building Dataframes in the following way inside a loop and save them into a list:

```
frame_list = []

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':0,'b':1,'c':1},columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=['z'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index=['y'])

frame_list.append(df1)

frame_list.append(df2)
```

After filling the list (round about 1000 entries so 1000 single Dataframes) I want to concatenate all of them into one big Dataframe.

```
final_frame = pd.concat(dataframe_list, axis=0)
```

Anyone knows how to speed up that process? For axis = 1 it runs fast, but thats not the representation of the data I want.

Best regards

I tried what I described and I was expecting a faster runtime.

Comment: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)  should work faster as you dont need to append to list

Comment: appending to the list works fast, just the concatenation of the single frames seems to run forever. Maybe an important information: i have very long string-column-names (uuids)

Comment: have you tried building a dictionary instead of dataframes in a loop? seems that you can do it and after then build one dataframe from dict

Comment: I will give it a try, maybe thats faster

Comment: It looks like you try to create a dataframe with a lot of columns but Pandas is not designed for this use-case. It is designed for dataframes with a small number of columns and a lot of rows. In fact, most dataframe library are not optimized for this use-case (R is known to have the same issues). Many algorithms runs in a `O(colCount²)` internally. Having large columns name does not help. Dicts are a good solution to scale better as adding items should be done in `O(1)` amortized time (and the name are not much a problem due to hashing (though the smaller the better)